# Highchart values overlap each other even when values are different

Tags: charts, highcharts, point, overlap

I have created multi series line chart in Highchart. I am facing a problem in it.
The line overlap each other even if the point values are different.
[image: overlapping points]

IN the image there are two lines for different data, the point values are different they are 22 and 793..

Comment: Probably going to need a JSFiddle on this one.

Comment: Do you have two different Y-axes defined for the two graphs?

Comment: @RononDex: I don't have two y-axes. It is a single graph with multiple series.

Comment: @Ondkloss: Sorry bro, actually the data comes from one server. I don't have its data structure.

Comment: I am facing this issue in both highchart and highstock.

Comment: I think that the chart shows the sum of the two points in the second line.
For eg: 25 apr the first value is 22 and second is 793 and the sum is 815. Therefore the point is plotted between  500 and 1000.

Comment: do you have stacking enabled perhaps?

Comment: Try to disable [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping), in other cases please harcoded piece of data and supply us demo.